# Will logging out of an Remote Desktop Session affect Windows Services that are running as that user?

Tags: windows

I have a Windows Server that runs some services as the same user account that is used to login via RDP.

If I log out of that RDP session will the Services be affected? I.e. as the user is no longer logged in will the services be no longer logged in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service will continue to work if it's coded correctly. If it need to interact with the desktop you must click to allow it in the services.msc's panel.

I mean correctly as if in exemple it depend on another process, that got a GUI attached to it to run, the process would fail.

Comment: +1 - pretty much...windows services will run non-interactively fine without the account logged in.  OP should bear in mind that creating actual service accounts is preferred vs. using a user account to run services (for a myriad of reasons I don't have enough characters to type here in a comment).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I inherited this set up and would prefer service accounts were used too.